# Obtain consistent outputs when using lapply and class on different data frames

Tags: r

I am trying to output a data frame which specifies the variable types for a given data frame. However, I am getting different results depending on the data frame. For example:

```
lapply(airquality, class) %>% data.frame
```

yields a usable single row data frame, but:

```
lapply(diamonds, class) %>% data.frame
```

yields a two row data frame where the desired information is only on the second row.

How can I obtain consistent results between the two data frames? I am happy with the output for `airquality`, but I would only like the second row of `diamonds`. I am only using these two data frames for this example, but I would like the solution to be robust to other data frames as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A column can have multiple classes. You can collapse them into one string.

```
lapply(airquality, function(x) toString(class(x))) %>% data.frame

#    Ozone Solar.R    Wind    Temp   Month     Day
#1 integer integer numeric integer integer integer

lapply(diamonds, function(x) toString(class(x))) %>% data.frame
#    carat             cut           color         clarity   depth   table
#1 numeric ordered, factor ordered, factor ordered, factor numeric numeric
#    price       x       y       z
#1 integer numeric numeric numeric
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak - one question though, when applying your solution to diamonds, the word `ordered` still appears alongside factors. is there anyway to have only 'factor' appear?

Comment: That is because those are ordered factors and that is how their class are shown. If you want them as only factors you can do something like this `sapply(diamonds, function(x) if(is.factor(x)) "factor" else toString(class(x)))`

Answer (score 1):

You can `sapply` over the columns with `type_sum`:

```r
sapply(airquality, pillar::type_sum)
# Ozone Solar.R    Wind    Temp   Month     Day 
# "int"   "int"   "dbl"   "int"   "int"   "int" 

sapply(diamonds, pillar::type_sum)
# carat     cut   color clarity   depth   table   price       x       y       z 
# "dbl"   "ord"   "ord"   "ord"   "dbl"   "dbl"   "int"   "dbl"   "dbl"   "dbl"
```

**Update**
Per OP comments about wanting to see "factor" and not "ordered", you can select the last class element for each data type.  For columns of type "ordered, factor", this will pull out only "factor":

```r
sapply(diamonds, function(x) class(x)[[length(class(x))]])
#  carat       cut     color   clarity     depth     table     price         x         y         z 
# "numeric"  "factor"  "factor"  "factor" "numeric" "numeric" "integer" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric"
```